# If no reputation change then why not hiding the date

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation-history

In reputation change section, if there is no reputation change in a particular date, the date will not be shown and it is [status-bydesign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

But today I was checking on a user's profile and saw this

[image]

Jun 29 is shown but no other dates are shown with no rep change(eg June 24-27)

Then I checked the graph but the date is not mentioned there

[image]

Is this a bug or any mod only details are there or did the rep change reversed in the same date?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means there *were* reputation changes - only they cancelled each other out.

For example - there was an upvote, but it was reversed.

You will note that there are many days that don't have that line at all - they don't show up (where's July 4th?).

Comment: so if they reversed at the same day, will the date stay there?

Comment: Yes. To indicate something happened.